# Should I ditch using `and_then` and always use the `?` operator?

Tags: error-handling, rust, rust-result

I want to write something like this, but it won't compile due to a mismatch between types:

```rust
fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let val = std::env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .ok_or("1 arg is expected")
        .and_then(std::fs::File::open)
        .and_then(serde_yaml::from_reader)?;
}
```

Because adding a `map_err` to every closure seems sluggish and 'boiler platy', I replace it with something like:

```rust
fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let val = serde_yaml::from_reader(std::fs::File::open(
        std::env::args().nth(1).ok_or("1 arg is expected")?,
    )?)?;
}
```

The first one feels more natural and reads like English while the second feels sort of backwards.

Should I ditch the `and_then` and always use the `?` operator?

If not, is there a way to make result combinator as smooth as the `?` operator?

Comment: You can always split it in several `let val` statements: `let val = env::args().nth (1).ok_or ("…")?; let val = File::open (val)?; let val = serde_yaml::from_reader (val)?;`

Comment: Or use a crate like [`map_for`](https://crates.io/crates/map_for), [`comp`](https://crates.io/crates/comp) or [`mdo`](https://crates.io/crates/mdo). Disclaimer: I wrote `map_for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I ditch the and_then and always use the ? operator ?

That’s a personal judgement and only you can answer it.

> Is there a way to make result combinator as smooth as the ? operator ?

Frankly speaking no. `?` performs conversions « implicitly » (not *really* implicitly since it’s very much part of its job, but the conversion doesn’t have to be invoked separately, maybe « tersely »?), `and_then` does not. That means when using `and_then`, you have to perform these conversions yourself. That seems logical.

You might be able to build a convenience macro for this tho. Or maybe add an extension method or wrapper type which can perform those conversions under the cover.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your first expression doesn't work is because the error types are not matching. To be more specific,

```
let val = std::env::args()
        .nth(1)
        .ok_or("1 arg is expected")
        .and_then(std::fs::File::open)
        .and_then(serde_yaml::from_reader)?;
```

`std::env::args().nth(1)` returns a `Option<T>`. If you look at the `ok_or` signature, which is `pub fn ok_or<E>(self, err: E) -> Result<T, E>`. This means for your case, `ok_or("1 arg is expected")` your return type is `Result<T, &str>`. So your error type here is `&str` because in ok_or, you pass a string slice as an Error type.

If you take a look at the `and_then` method, the signature is `pub fn and_then<U, F>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E> where F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E>`, basically this means the Function you passed in and_then should have the same error type as the original Result, which is a `&str`. This is same as the line `.and_then(serde_yaml::from_reader)`, the error types needs to be consistent for all the "chaining" and_then functions.

If you really want, you can do the following way to make your code compile. Or you can create a uniform error so no mismatch error types. Then you can use the `ok_or(...).and_then(...).and_then(...)` kind of writing. You just need to match the error types.

working example

```rust
fn custom_fs_open(path: String) -> Result<String, &'static str>{
    // actual logics to open fs
    Ok(String::from("abc"))
}


fn custom_serde_yaml(buf: String) -> Result<String, &'static str>{
    // actual logics to do serde convertion
    Ok(String::from("cde"))
}


fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let val = std::env::args()
            .nth(1)
            .ok_or("1 arg is expected")
            .and_then(custom_fs_open)
            .and_then(custom_serde_yaml)?;
            
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: The OP already knows this: "adding a `map_err` to every closure seems sluggish and 'boiler platy'"